# Extract number, remove duplicate and separate with a comma in Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe

Need help extracting multiple numbers from a column in a dataframe and remove duplicates and separate them with a comma.

| Col1 |
| --- |
| Abcde 10 hijk20 |
| wewrw5 gagdhdh5 |
| Mnbjgkh10,20, 30 |

Expected output;

| Col2 |
| --- |
| 10,20 |
| 5 |
| 10,20,30 |

Comment: Please let me know if my answer answers your question (:

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? `findall()` from the `re` module with the regular expression `r'\d+'` returns a list containing all non-overlapping matches of one or more consecutive decimal digits in the string. The built-in `set()` removes any duplicates from that list and applying the `sorted()` built-in returns a sorted list of the elements in the set. We also make use of `numpy.vectorize` as it is faster than `apply()` from Pandas for this particular application (at least on my system) though I have shown how to use `apply()` as well.

**Method 1**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import re

# compile RE - matches one or more decimal digits
p = re.compile(r'\d+')

# data
d = {'col1': ['Abcde 10 hijk20', 'wewrw5 gagdhdh5', 'Mnbjgkh10,20, 30'],
     'col2': [''] * 3}

# DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# modify col2 based on col1
df['col2'] = np.vectorize(
    lambda y:  ','.join(sorted(set(p.findall(y)))),
    )(df['col1'])

print(df)
```

Output

```
               col1      col2
0   Abcde 10 hijk20     10,20
1   wewrw5 gagdhdh5         5
2  Mnbjgkh10,20, 30  10,20,30
```

If you can only use `pandas` and not `numpy`, you can do

**Method 2**

```
# modify col2 based on col1
df['col2'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(sorted(set(p.findall(x['col1'])))) , axis=1)
```

or even
**Method 3**

```
# modify col2 based on col1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['col2'] = ','.join(sorted(set(p.findall(row['col1']))))
```

**Efficiency**

---

On my system, `vectorize` (method 1) is fastest, method 3 is second fastest and method 2 is the slowest.

```
# Method 1
82.9 µs ± 170 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
# Method 2
399 µs ± 8.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# Method 3
117 µs ± 178 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
punctuations = ['!','(',')','-','[',']','{','}',';',':','"','<','>','.','/','?']
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    content = dataframe.iloc[index:index, column_index]
    for p in punctuations:
        content.replace(p, " ")
    only_numbers = re.sub("[^0-9]", " ", content)
    only_numbers.strip()
    numbers_found = only_numbers.split(" ")
    no_duplicates = list(set(numbers_found))
    comma_separated = ",".join(no_duplicates)
    dataframe.iloc[index:index, column_index] = comma_separated
```